# how to use mvc4 model value in knockout viewmodel js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am using Knockout with ASP.NET MVC here is my View which is populated by MVC controller

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" />
 <script src="/Scripts/ViewModel.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
public actionresult xyz(){
  var myModel = new FiestModel();
  myModel.Name = "James";
  return view(myModel);
}
```

**ViewModel.Js**

```
function mymode(){
  var self = this ;
  self.Name = ko.observable('@Model.Name');
}
```

after doing all of this when my page render my input doesn't have the specified value `James` .

**Update**

I tell you guys about the whole scenario , in my application a user click on `signup with facebook` button and facebook return user back to my `xyz` action method , now i want to show the username in `xyz` view . So how can i do this with api because @Anders said me to do this by Web APi .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldnt mix server side MVC and client side MVVM.
Move the model population to a WebAPI controller method.

Load the data using jQuery.getJSON or other framework for Ajax
You can also use ko.mapping to map the server data into ViewModels

edit: code in ViewModel.js have to be moved to the cshtml file if oyu want to use 
@Mode.Name, but please dont do it.

**Update**
Something along the lines

```
[HttpGet]
public FiestModel xyz() {
   return new FiestModel("James");
}
```

With mapping plugin something like

```
ViewModel = function(data) {
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

$.getJSON("api/myController/xyz", null, function(data) {
   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
});
```

Comment: see my update in question , i described my whole scenario . Hopefully now you can help me in better way . thanks

Comment: That was a broad question :D You can still use Standard controls, but skip using Razor engine to get the data instead use Ajax to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like on JS:

```
function myModel(){
   var data = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
   this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
}
```

Then you bind your view model:

```
ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

Comment: Inline/Unobstrusive JS is a anti pattern